# Jquery pushstate body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, replacewith

I am using jquery pushstate to replace a container and the head title - (which is working fine).

However, I also need to **replace the body class** in the same format but struggling...

Here is the code so far (not the full script):

```
function handle_pushstate_navigation() {
    var state = History.getState(),
        url   = state.url;

    $.ajax({
        url:     url,
        success: function(html) {
            var $html      = $(html),
                $container = $('.leftcontent'),
                title      = $html.filter('title').text()

            $('title').text(title);
            $container.replaceWith($html.find('.leftcontent'));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the body class snippet I've been experimenting with:

```
$bodyclass = $('body').attr('class'),
$bodyclass.replaceWith($('body').attr('class'));
```

Your help and guidance would mean a lot.

Comment: No, I am switching pages and pulling the body class from the targeted page into the current body class area. - If that makes sense?

Comment: Nope. You can change classes only of current page. You can add class: `$('body').addClass('className');`, you can remove specific class: `$('body').removeClass('className');`, you can remove all classes: `$('body').removeClass();`, you can toggle class: `$('body').toggleClass('className');`. But all these actions can be done only with currently loaded page.

Comment: So how is the page title pulled in? Surely the body class can be pulled too?

Comment: Well, I didn't look at your code. Since you are loading another page into container via ajax, you can use `$('body').attr('class', $html.find('body').attr('class'));`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is comin up as 'undefined' ?

Comment: What exactly is `undefined`? You can also try `$html.filter('body')` instead of `$html.find('body')`